# Combinations exercise, choose 3 from first group, 3 from 2nd group and *three from either*.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> A club with 32 boys and 36 girls needs to form a committee of size nine. How many committees with
> at least three girls and at least three boys can be formed?
> The source is a professor's assignment in a Discrete Math course.

At first this appeared simple.

$$(_{32}C_{3})*(_{36}C_{3})*(_{62}C_{3})$$

with 62 coming from 29 boys left + 33 girls left to choose from.

This is choose 3 boys * choose 3 girls * choose 3 of either.
However, this has duplicates.  Let B1 represent 1st boy & G1 represent the 1st girl.

B1, B2, B3, G1, G2, G3, B4, B5, B6  is the same committee as

B1, B5, B6, G1, G2, G3, B4, B2, B3

A. How do I compensate for duplicates like these and any other duplicates?

B. If an entirely other approach is required, please share.

Comment: I tried searching but am not sure how to search for this.  "Combinations" and "free" didn't help.  Does this type of problem have a name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the $4$ cases where $0,1,2,3$ boys are from the last case (or similar, $b = 3$ up to $6$ boys in the set of $9$, complemented with $9-b$ girls.

$$\sum_{b=3}^{6}C(32, b)*C(36, 9-b) $$

Such formulas are perfectly fine as an answer. A single term does not exist, and the resulting exact value is optional: it does not show your understanding or how you came to the solution.

Final value: [image: **]

Yes, I admit, I used Excel:

[image]

Comment: A. Hmmm, essentially this same answer occurred to me while I was trying to nap.  
B. I would clarify, a single term as a method is not sufficient.  We need to break it down into (3B, 6G) + (4B, 5G) + (5B, 4G) + (6B, 3G)  They have a sum which is a single term.  Most profs would like to see both the method and the final number as a single term.
Thanks.

Comment: @nickalh  What Pieter21 did was obtain the sum $\binom{32}{3}\binom{36}{6} + \binom{32}{4}\binom{36}{5} + \binom{32}{5}\binom{36}{4} + \binom{32}{6}\binom{36}{3}$ by considering the four cases you mentioned.  That expression can be evaluated, but it does not simplify to a single term.

Comment: ummm, if you evaluate each expression, then simplify by multiplying and finally adding it becomes a single term.  A correct answer would clarify that.  Clear communication is incredibly helpful, especially when we don't have voice inflections, may be coming from entirely different trains of thought, perspectives, etc.